# Visual Studio doesn't generate the iOS "ipa" executable with Xamarin

Tags: iphone, visual-studio-2015, build, xamarin.ios, ipa

I am trying to generate the `ipa` file in order to publish it to the Apple Store but Visual Studio (2015 Community Edition) doesn't create it.

I followed the steps from the [official Xamarin docs](https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/ios/deployment,_testing,_and_metrics/app_distribution/ipa_support/#Creating_an_IPA) but it doesn't work, I tried selecting "AdHoc", "Release" and "AppStore" (with iPhone platform selected), I have the last Xamarin updates in my Windows and Mac build hosts, the build process ends succesfully but the ipa file doesn't appear in the `**Bin > iPhone > Ad Hoc (or Release)` folder.

I am using the distribution profile.

I would really appreciate any help.

Answer (score 2):

A combination of clearing the bin/iPhone/Ad-Hoc folder, changing the build number, restarting Visual Studio, and re-connecting to the Mac resolved this for me.